# NSMutableDictionary setObject forKey forKey...etc

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm trying to setObjects that are deep in my NSMutableDictionary, by that I mean there are a few levels of keys before I can get to them.

Obviously I can't do

```
setObject:x forKey forKey forKey forKey...
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use key-path coding. Something like:

```
[myDictionary setValue:newValue forKeyPath:@"foo.bar.baz"];
```

That looks up `foo` on `myDictionary`, then takes whatever it gets and looks up `bar` on that, then takes whatever it gets that time and calls `setValue:forKey:` on that to assign a new value for `baz`. You can also use key paths to look up values:

```
id currentValue = [myDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"foo.bar.baz"];
```

Answer (score 6):

You would just do something like

```
mutableDictionary[key1][key2][key3] = value;
```

**BUT** this multi nesting of dictionaries is most likely hinting at a bigger problem with your design.